# Imperial Star Destroyer: Exact bridge location?

Tags: star-wars

I have a rather trivial question:

I would like to know where the ***exact*** location of a Imperial Star Destroyer bridge is.

We all know, that the bridge looks as follows from the outside:
[image: outside bridge]

This bridge design applies to most of the imperial ships (the *Executor*, *Avanger*, *Imperator*, *Eradicator*, *Valor* etc.)

But we also know, that the inside view of the bridge looks as follows:
[image: inside bridge]

The interior is the same for all Imperial class-I and -II Star Destroyers **and** for the Republican Star Destroyers (*Venator*, *Acclamator*, *Victory*, *Tector* etc.)

The problem is that I don't know where exactly the command bridge is located on the Imperial I/II Ships due to the very different inside and outside bridge layouts *(It is pretty obvious for the Republican Ships ...)*

---

Could someone help me with my confusion? :D

Comment: Do you mind if I use your picture of the bridge as a reference?

Comment: @LadyStark: No, of course I do not mind. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the cross-section book, the command bridge on Imperial-I and Imperial-II class Star Destroyers is located in the exact center of the tower tweedle. [image: Cross section]

Comment: Please tell me you didn't just make up the word "tweedle"? :)  +1 just for that word

Comment: @DVK it's something my wife uses all the time, and it's permeated into my vocabulary.  I think the technical term is greeble, thingie, that sort of thing

Comment: Is that schematic canon? (I'm surprised there at the star destroyer an IMP2 I assume? having ONLY SIX turo lasers and twelve ion canons if I'm reading the shematics rights?)

Comment: @Thomas The text says there are six of the heaviest type. That does not preclude the existence of more, smaller turbolasers.

Comment: @T.J.L. I was only surprised there as older sources like the rpgs,... talked about 100 turbolasers,...     in the rogue one film I also saw only a HANDFUL of large turbolaser canons (and only these canons) on the destroyers

Answer (score 6):

The Bridge is located in the middle of this red circle.
[image: Exact Location of the Bridge]

Comment: That's the roundest square I've ever seen. Also, could you expand a bit and tell us _why_ you think it's in that location? Do you have any sources?

Comment: @SQB IMHo it looks exactly like the windws seen on the "bridge from inside" picture  OP posted. Schematics posted in the answer by CBredlow also points straight there

Answer (score 6):

The image you have was probably an ISD model from ANH when they hadn't thought about the ISD's bridge windows yet.
Take a look at a different ISD model Lucasfilm they used in ROTJ, it very clearly shows the bridge.
This video shows the bridge of an ISD II at 3:15.

Comment: In the video above, at 6:48.
You can clearly see flames spewing from where the A-wing stuck (which was the bridge).

Comment: The vieo has been blocked due to copyright issues with disney as it seems

Answer (score 2):

In Nintendo GameCube "Star Wars: Rogue Squadron 2", a model that takes into account the position of the bridge will appear

Answer (score -1):

Right there in the middle where it is round with the triangular windows. [image]

Comment: Please explain where you got this image. How do we know it's from an Imperial Star Destroyer?

Comment: looks like Rebels level rendering

Comment: I found it in the first episode and season of Star Wars: Rebels. You can tell it's a star destroyer by the other star destroyers in the background and the general shape of the bridge. Since Star Wars: Rebels doesn't focus on star destroyers that much, it might not be in scale. However, it provides a clear location where the bridge would be. Also, look at this link to tell it's an ISD: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKU5C8bvJxA&list=PLtdzqoUSfzvYByiZ1JAZnVBH3dONYDL5V&ab_channel=StarWars The bridge of star destroyers are also circular and rounded at the front

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is in the very top of the star destroyer[image]

Comment: Could you expand a bit and tell us why you think it's in that location? Do you have any sources?

Comment: well I believe it’s in the very front of the nose, doesn’t make it so